# how could I sort the data based on categories in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Being a newbie I am not able to know how to sort my posts based on categories which I have created in WordPress. I am getting my all posts because of the following code mentioned on image:
[image]

```
<?php $recent = new WP_Query(
"post_type=post&posts_per_page=6&orderby=date&order=DESC"); 
>
```

Navigation bar is my categories. So on clicking each category I should get posts relevant to that category only. For example clicking on Recipes, I should get all posts related to recipes only. Please suggest me plugins (jQuery) to give that tab the kind of functionality and how I am gonna implement this sort or filter sort of functionality in WordPress. Please help me with some code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So your code is an image?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois bro
  <?php $recent = new WP_Query("post_type=post&posts_per_page=6&orderby=date&order=DESC");

Comment: Sorry,Its not showing up in the description section.

Answer (score 0):

For best of my knowledge and if I m guessing you right.
make category.php(For wordpress post) or taxonomy.php(for custom post type taxonomy)

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the category as a menu.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$wpq = array( 
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'taxonomy' => 'category', 
    'term' => 'category-slug' 
);
$recent = new WP_Query ($wpq);
```

NOTE: change 'category-slug' with correct Category slug